# Using formtastic how to wrap label output in custom class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

Right now I am outputting 3 radio buttons with formtastic.

```
<label for="exercise_log_entries_attributes_0_difficulty_medium">
 <input checked="checked" class="custom radio" data-placeholder="Difficulty" id="exercise_log_entries_attributes_0_difficulty_medium" name="exercise[log_entries_attributes][0][difficulty]" type="radio" value="Medium">
 Medium
</label>
```

I want to wrap "medium" in a custom class. How can I do this?

Figured out the answer:

Have to use `member_label`:

```
member_label: Proc.new {|a| "<span class='custom radio'>#{a}</span>".html_safe}
```

Comment: can you try passing `label: '<div class="myclass">Medium</div>'.html_safe`. not sure it will owrk though

Comment: That created a label / legend for the whole wrapper instead of the individual pieces.

Comment: can you include your formtastic code in your question?

Comment: I figured it out. Here's the answer: member_label: Proc.new {|a| "<span class='custom radio'>#{a}</span>".html_safe}

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
member_label: Proc.new {|a| "<span class='custom radio'>#{a}</span>".html_safe}
```